# In Javascript, how do I make an Audio object reload repeatedly/recursively on an error?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I am making software that relies on streaming audio from a URL for files stored on Google Drive that will timeout and fail after about 5 minutes of idling.  When it does this, I would like the audio link to refresh, and also set the time to where the audio was previously.

To expound upon the idea see the sample code below:

```
export default class ReloadingAudio {
    constructor(url) {
        this.audio = new Audio(url)
        this.audio.onerror = () => {
            this.audio = new Audio(url)
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine to reload the audio the first time, but because the second new Audio created has no onerror function, when it times out again, it does not reload.

I was wondering, well, firstly, is there any way to prevent the audio time out on Google drive files in the first place (it turns into a 403 forbidden error) in which case I don't need to do this, and secondly, is there a good way to recursively define the onerror function such that no matter how many times the audio times out it will repeatedly reload?

Thank you!

**Edit**

Wanted to add, I did discover a solution for this, but I tried just changing the AudioElement's src and that was equally effective of a solution (and I imagine better for memory purposes.)  However, for the curious, here is a way to recursively reset the audio, you can define the function like this:

```
export default class ReloadingAudio {
    constructor(url) {
        this.audio = new Audio(url)

        const self = this

        function onerrorFunction() {
            self.audio = new Audio(url)
            self.audio.onerror = onerrorFunction
        }

        this.audio.onerror = onerrorFunction
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to prevent the timeouts caused by Google Drive but you might get the intended behavior by re-setting the `src` to the `url` on your existing `AudioElement`.

```
this.audio.onerror = () => {
    this.audio.src = url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this does produce the intended effect in I think a better fashion than resetting the whole AudioElement :)